# Text align in a box decoration

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this `box decoration` used for showing the reviews but I don't know what I should use to `align` the `text` properly. This is how it looks right now:

[image]

I want the username ("La fottaria to have some space left) I used Align( Alignment(8,3)) but it doesn't change the position.

```
return ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
      width: 200,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 8, bottom: 8, right: 12),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
              blurRadius: 2,
              spreadRadius: 1)
      ], borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
      child: Column(
          children: [
          Row(
              children: [
              CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      snapshot.data.documents[index]
                          .data["avatarUrl"]),
              ),
              Align(
                  alignment: Alignment(8, 3),
                  child: Text(snapshot
                      .data
                      .documents[index]
                      .data["name"]),
              )
              ],
          ),
          _buildRatingStars(snapshot.data
              .documents[index].data["rating"]),
          Text(snapshot
              .data.documents[index].data["text"])
          ],
      ),
      );
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `Row` widget, you can use a `SizedBox` with `width` property.

It will give some space.

```
Row(
  children: [
    CircleAvatar(
     backgroundImage:
         NetworkImage(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["avatarUrl"]),
    ),

    //insert here

    SizedBox(
      width: 20.0,
    ),

    Align(
      alignment: Alignment(8, 3),
      child: Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["name"]),
    )
  ],
)
```

You can remove the `Align` widget if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `align` widget, I suggest you to use `Container` widget like this:

```
Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
  child: Text(snapshot
   .data
   .documents[index]
   .data["name"]),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Align`

Example:

```
DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.blue,
          width: 1,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
      ),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center, // align type
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 15),
          child: Text(
            title,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.blue),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use some inbuilt property of rows i.e Main Axis Alignment and Cross Axis Alignment to align its children.For eg:

```
     Row(
         mainAxisAligment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
         crossAxisAligment:CrossAxisAligment.center,
         children: [
           CircleAvatar(
             backgroundImage:
              NetworkImage(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["avatarUrl"]),
              ),         
           SizedBox(
            width: 20.0,
                 ),
           Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["name"]),
                  ],
       )
```

You can wrap the text widget inside padding widget also to align according to your needs.